# How to write Sql code to group objects within a specified time interval?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as the one shown below (Table 1). I would like to find out using sql how many objects are bought by each customer within one month from each other. The output table should like Table 2.

Table 1

```
-----------------------------
Customer    Date      Object
-----------------------------
C1          D1        O1
C1          D2        O2
C1          D3        O3
C2          D1        O4
C2          D2        O5
-----------------------------
```

Table 2

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of objects   Number of customers    Start Date      End Date
--------------------------------------------------------------------
4                   2                       D1             D2
1                   1                       D3             D3
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*the first row 4 objects: O1, O2, O3 and O4 and 2 customer: C1, C2 (based on the Table1)

I wrote a code to answer the question of how many objects are bought on the same date. I am a bit stuck on how I need to modify this now to answer question above?

```sql
    CREATE TABLE Tab AS (
        select Customer, Date, count(distinct Object) as number_objects
        from Database
        group by Customer, Date
    );
```

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out what you are looking for. To start with, what is `Table2`: sample data or expected result? And what is the logic that relates `Table1` to `Table2`?

Comment: why 4 2 D1 D2, 1 1 D3 D3 ? Why not 2 2 D1 D1, 3 2 D2 D3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just count for each calendar month?

```
select year(date), month(date),
       count(distinct customer) as num_customers,
       count(distinct object) as num_objects
from tab
group by year(date), month(date);
```